# Show that the Fourier coefficient satisfies the following inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $h \in BV[-\pi,\pi]$ ( it is of bounded variation). Consider $\pi a_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)cos(nx)dx$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ we have to show that $\lvert a_n \rvert$ $\leq$ $2/n$ $V_{-\pi}^\pi$$f$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and $V$ is the variation of the function $f$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$

Attempt:
So if we consider $x_k = -\pi + 2\pi k /n$ where k = 0,...,n then the integral $\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}} cos(nx)dx = 0$ How do we proceed after this could someone fill in the details? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

For $n > 0$,
\begin{align}
    &\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)\cos(nx)dx \\
    & = \left.h(x)\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\right|_{x=-\pi}^{\pi}-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}dh(x).
\end{align}
This is because integration by parts always holds as shown above.
Therefore,
$$
  \left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)\cos(nx)dx\right| \le \frac{1}{n}V_{-\pi}^{\pi}(h),\;\; n > 0.
$$
For $n=0$, it is true that  $|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}h(x)dx| \le V_{-\pi}^{\pi}(h)$.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail on the second inequality involving the variation of h? Thank you for your help

Comment: @user555483 : The evalution terms vanish, and $|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}dh(x)| \le \frac{1}{n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|dh|=\frac{1}{n}V_{-\pi}^{\pi}(h)$.